# html is not consistent show on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hey everyone i have a grid, grid have edit button. when i click the edit button call method and this method have 3 new methods, all 3 methods are have ajax request to controller and get the view and append in the div. but problem is some time its show the div with html but some time its show empty divs why this behaviuor div is empty please help me what should i do..

this all 3 divs

```
            <div id="Div1"></div>
            <div id="Div2"></div>
            <div id="Div3"></div>
```

this main function who calling other functions

```
 function main(Url1, Url2, Url3) {
                func1(Url1);
                func2(Url2);
                func3(Url3);
            }
```

all 3 functions

```
    function func1(page) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: page,
                    data: $("#Data").serialize(),
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (html) {
                        $('#Div1').empty();
                        $('#Div1').append($.parseHTML(html));
                    },
                    error: function () {
                    alert("Error");      
        },
                    complete: function () {
                        //complete
                    }
                });
            }

function func2(page) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: page,
                    data: $("#Data").serialize(),
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (html) {
                        $('#Div2').empty();
                        $('#Div2').append($.parseHTML(html));
                    },
                    error: function () {
                    alert("Error");      
        },
                    complete: function () {
                        //complete
                    }
                });
            }

function func3(page) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: page,
                    data: $("#Data").serialize(),
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (html) {
                        $('#Div3').empty();
                        $('#Div3').append($.parseHTML(html));
                    },
                    error: function () {
                    alert("Error");      
        },
                    complete: function () {
                        //complete
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: try add timeout function because js and your ajax calls are asynchronous. Take a while for response arrived.

Comment: What does $("#Data").serialize() return?

Answer (score 1):

its better to create just one function not 3

```
function func(element , page) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: page,
                    data: $("#Data").serialize(),
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (html) {
                        $(element).empty();
                        $(element).append($.parseHTML(html));
                    },
                    error: function () {
                       alert("Error");      
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        //complete
                    }
                });
            }
```

and use it like this

```
function main(Url1, Url2, Url3) {
                func('#Div1',Url1);
                func('#Div2',Url2);
                func('#Div3',Url3);
            }
```

Finally as for any ajax request

1- check url file connection

2- check data you passed from ajax

3- check data which returned to success function

Comment: @daremachine take ajax out the function and use it in $(document).ready() .. if it works good return it to the function again .. it will work then